How can I identify silences in audio in Node.js?
I'm working on implementing a real time chatbot using openai's GPT4o model, so far I've got mostly everything working except one key piece which is knowing when the audio streamed by the frontend is voice vs silence. I thought this was going to be trivial to solve but turns out it's not haha.
EDIT: One key thing I forgot to mention, the issue I'm facing is that by chaging my thresholds no matter what values I use I either always get silence detected or always get voice detected.
This is my current AudioProcessor class
import logger from "node-color-log";
import { logToFile } from "./tempLog";
const { fft } = require("fft-js");
const AudioBuffer = require("audio-buffer");

export class AudioProcessor {
  private rmsHistory: number[];
  private zcrHistory: number[];
  private historySize: number;
  private silenceThreshold: number;
  private zcrThreshold: number;
  private centroidThreshold: number;
  private rmsThreshold: number;

  constructor(
    historySize: number = 5,
    silenceThreshold: number = -30,
    zcrThreshold: number = 0.1,
    centroidThreshold: number = 500,
    rmsThreshold: number = 0.01
  ) {
    this.rmsHistory = [];
    this.zcrHistory = [];
    this.historySize = historySize;
    this.silenceThreshold = silenceThreshold;
    this.zcrThreshold = zcrThreshold;
    this.centroidThreshold = centroidThreshold;
    this.rmsThreshold = rmsThreshold;
  }

  private addToHistory(history: number[], value: number) {
    if (history.length >= this.historySize) {
      history.shift(); // Remove the oldest value
    }
    history.push(value);
  }

  private calculateSmoothedAverage(history: number[]): number {
    const sum = history.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
    return sum / history.length;
  }

  private convertBufferToAudioBuffer(buffer: Buffer): any {
    // Assuming mono channel audio and 16-bit samples
    const samples = new Int16Array(
      buffer.buffer,
      buffer.byteOffset,
      buffer.length / Int16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
    );
    const floatSamples = new Float32Array(samples.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
      floatSamples[i] = samples[i] / 32768.0; // Normalize to range [-1, 1]
    }
    const audioBuffer = new AudioBuffer({
      length: floatSamples.length,
      sampleRate: 44100, // Adjust sample rate as per your data
      numberOfChannels: 1,
    });
    audioBuffer.copyToChannel(floatSamples, 0);
    return audioBuffer;
  }

  public calculateRMS(buffer: Buffer): number {
    const audioBuffer = this.convertBufferToAudioBuffer(buffer);
    const samples = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    const sum = samples.reduce(
      (acc: number, val: number) => acc + val * val,
      0
    );
    return Math.sqrt(sum / samples.length);
  }

  public calculateZCR(buffer: Buffer): number {
    const audioBuffer = this.convertBufferToAudioBuffer(buffer);
    const samples = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    let zeroCrossings = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i < samples.length; i++) {
      if (
        (samples[i] > 0 && samples[i - 1] < 0) ||
        (samples[i] < 0 && samples[i - 1] > 0)
      ) {
        zeroCrossings++;
      }
    }

    return zeroCrossings / samples.length;
  }

  private padArrayToNextPowerOf2(array: Float32Array): Float32Array {
    const targetLength = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log2(array.length)));
    const paddedArray = new Float32Array(targetLength);
    paddedArray.set(array);
    return paddedArray;
  }

  public calculateSpectralCentroid(buffer: Buffer): number {
    try {
      const audioBuffer = this.convertBufferToAudioBuffer(buffer);
      const samples = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);

      const signal = this.padArrayToNextPowerOf2(samples);
      const phasors = fft(signal);

      let sum = 0;
      let weightedSum = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < phasors.length / 2; i++) {
        const magnitude = Math.sqrt(
          phasors[i][0] * phasors[i][0] + phasors[i][1] * phasors[i][1]
        );

        sum += magnitude;
        weightedSum += i * magnitude;
      }

      if (sum === 0) {
        return 0; // Avoid division by zero
      }

      return weightedSum / sum;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.color("red").log(`Error calculating spectral centroid: ${error}`);
      return 0; // Return a default value in case of error
    }
  }

  public isSilence(buffer: Buffer): boolean {
    try {
      const rms = this.calculateRMS(buffer);
      const decibels = 20 * Math.log10(rms);
      const zcr = this.calculateZCR(buffer);
      const spectralCentroid = this.calculateSpectralCentroid(buffer);

      this.addToHistory(this.rmsHistory, rms);
      this.addToHistory(this.zcrHistory, zcr);

      const smoothedRMS = this.calculateSmoothedAverage(this.rmsHistory);
      const smoothedZCR = this.calculateSmoothedAverage(this.zcrHistory);

      // Calculate mean, variance, and skewness
      const audioBuffer = this.convertBufferToAudioBuffer(buffer);
      const samples = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);
      const mean =
        samples.reduce((acc: number, val: number) => acc + val, 0) /
        samples.length;
      const variance =
        samples.reduce(
          (acc: number, val: number) => acc + (val - mean) * (val - mean),
          0
        ) / samples.length;
      const skewness =
        samples.reduce(
          (acc: number, val: number) => acc + Math.pow(val - mean, 3),
          0
        ) /
        samples.length /
        Math.pow(variance, 1.5);

      logger.color("white").log("------------------------------------------");
      logger.color("blue").log(`Average RMS amplitude: ${rms}`);
      logger.color("blue").log(`Decibels: ${decibels}`);
      logger.color("blue").log(`Zero Crossing Rate: ${zcr}`);
      logger.color("blue").log(`Spectral Centroid: ${spectralCentroid}`);
      logger.color("blue").log(`Smoothed RMS amplitude: ${smoothedRMS}`);
      logger.color("blue").log(`Smoothed ZCR: ${smoothedZCR}`);
      logger.color("blue").log(`Mean: ${mean}`);
      logger.color("blue").log(`Variance: ${variance}`);
      logger.color("blue").log(`Skewness: ${skewness}`);

      const smoothedDecibels = 20 * Math.log10(smoothedRMS);

      const silenceScore =
        (smoothedDecibels <= this.silenceThreshold ? 1 : 0) +
        (smoothedZCR <= this.zcrThreshold ? 1 : 0) +
        (spectralCentroid < this.centroidThreshold ? 1 : 0) +
        (smoothedRMS < this.rmsThreshold ? 1 : 0);

      const isSilent = silenceScore >= 3; // Consider it silent if 3 or more conditions are met

      logger
        .color(isSilent ? "red" : "green")
        .log(`Silence detected: ${isSilent}`);
      logger.color("white").log("------------------------------------------");

      // Log data to file
      logToFile({
        rms,
        decibels,
        zcr,
        spectralCentroid,
        smoothedRMS,
        smoothedZCR,
        mean,
        variance,
        skewness,
        samples: samples.slice(0, 100), // Log first 100 samples as an example
        silenceScore,
        isSilent,
      });

      return isSilent;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.color("red").log(`Error processing audio: ${error}`);
      logToFile({ error: `Error processing audio: ${error}` });
      return false; // Return false in case of error to avoid false positives
    }
  }
}


As you migh deduce from the comments on the file, I've been trying to solve this with GPT's help because I'm not that good with audio theory (Complete noob tbh) And no matter how hard I try I can't seem to figgure out audio features that differentiate between silence and voice.
Here are some plot analysis I made in a google collab to try and understand the audio I'm recieving from my frontend.







I feel like I might be trying to reinvent the wheel here and I'm guessing that either 1) This is not a trivial problem and there are good ways to do this or 2) This is already solved and there might be some library or some better way to do this already known.
Disclaimer: This is just a personal project of mine and all I'm trying to do is learn more about audio processing and audio streaming using TTS and STT. Any reources you might think I could find usefull are GREATLY apreciated. Thanks!!
Edit 2:
With this simpler aproach
import logger from "node-color-log";
import { logToFile } from "./tempLog";
const { fft } = require("fft-js");
const AudioBuffer = require("audio-buffer");

export class AudioProcessor {
  private frequencyThreshold: number;

  constructor(frequencyThreshold: number = 3000) {
    this.frequencyThreshold = frequencyThreshold;
  }

  private convertBufferToAudioBuffer(buffer: Buffer): any {
    const samples = new Int16Array(
      buffer.buffer,
      buffer.byteOffset,
      buffer.length / Int16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
    );
    const floatSamples = new Float32Array(samples.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
      floatSamples[i] = samples[i] / 32768.0; // Normalize to range [-1, 1]
    }
    const audioBuffer = new AudioBuffer({
      length: floatSamples.length,
      sampleRate: 44100,
      numberOfChannels: 1,
    });
    audioBuffer.copyToChannel(floatSamples, 0);
    return audioBuffer;
  }

  private padArrayToNextPowerOf2(array: Float32Array): Float32Array {
    const targetLength = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log2(array.length)));
    const paddedArray = new Float32Array(targetLength);
    paddedArray.set(array);
    return paddedArray;
  }

  private calculateSpectralCentroid(samples: Float32Array): number {
    const signal = this.padArrayToNextPowerOf2(samples);
    const phasors = fft(signal);

    let sum = 0;
    let weightedSum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < phasors.length / 2; i++) {
      const magnitude = Math.sqrt(
        phasors[i][0] * phasors[i][0] + phasors[i][1] * phasors[i][1]
      );
      sum += magnitude;
      weightedSum += i * magnitude;
    }

    if (sum === 0) {
      return 0; // Avoid division by zero
    }

    return weightedSum / sum;
  }

  public isSilence(buffer: Buffer): boolean {
    try {
      const audioBuffer = this.convertBufferToAudioBuffer(buffer);
      const samples = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);

      const spectralCentroid = this.calculateSpectralCentroid(samples);

      logger.color("white").log(`Spectral Centroid: ${spectralCentroid}`);

      // Adjusted threshold for silence detection
      const isSilent = spectralCentroid < this.frequencyThreshold;

      logger
        .color(isSilent ? "red" : "green")
        .log(`Silence detected: ${isSilent}`);

      // Log data to file
      logToFile({
        spectralCentroid,
        samples: samples.slice(0, 100), // Log first 100 samples as an example
        isSilent,
      });

      return isSilent;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.color("red").log(`Error processing audio: ${error}`);
      logToFile({ error: `Error processing audio: ${error}` });
      return false; // Return false in case of error to avoid false positives
    }
  }
}

I can detect when I just stoped speaking but can't detect ongoing silence. So if I start recording and the audio is silent, and then start speaking and then stop, at that point I'll detect the "user stoped speaking" beacuse the value of the spectralCentroid goes down by half for that split moment, and then goes back up to normal even if I'm silent. You can see it in these logs:
{
  "2024-05-26T07:46:25.660Z": { // Not speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 2037.8454168899564,
    "isSilent": true
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:26.704Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4110.142437287381,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:27.738Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4103.634296559709,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:28.743Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4075.653243813843,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:29.762Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4086.247405654429,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:30.780Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4101.284325704628,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:31.803Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4086.706973284889,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:32.817Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4090.586142710563,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:33.832Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4103.814745362072,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:34.850Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4078.1058355683026,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:35.870Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4124.73843481549,
    "isSilent": false
  }, 
  "2024-05-26T07:46:36.891Z": { // Speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 4074.536211925613,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:37.890Z": { // Not speaking
    "spectralCentroid": 2043.2772409037066,
    "isSilent": true
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:38.930Z": { // Not speaking but value goes back up
    "spectralCentroid": 4087.244236237976,
    "isSilent": false
  },
  "2024-05-26T07:46:39.951Z": { // Not speaking but value stays up
    "spectralCentroid": 4086.876461033878,
    "isSilent": false
  },
}

When the recording starts the value corresponds to a silence for one data point, then I start speaking, then I shut up and we get this new single data point
"2024-05-26T07:46:37.890Z": {
    "spectralCentroid": 2043.2772409037066,
    "isSilent": true
  },

And after that all other logs are from me being silent, but still the value goes back up. So right now I'm able to detect when I just shuted up but can't detect ongoing silence.

Can you provide a sample? It's unclear why the threshold doesn't work

It's on the plots, the issue seem to be that both the silent and voice audio data have values on the same tresholds, so no matter what treshhold I set both the silent pieces of the audio and the voice pieces have about the same range, except for the spectralCentroid in which case the value goes down exactly when I stop speaking but it then goes back up after even if I stay quiet. Meaning I only got to the point of being able to detect sudden silence but not prolonged silence. Does this answer your question? Or is there anything else I can do to provide more info?

Yes, I mean it needs to be checked why exactly this happens. Does audio data comes from a mic? Probably some kind of normalization takes place. In order to get proper silence you'd probably need to denoise first, then regular threshold would work. And if you need this to extract voice parts then voice detection could be used instead because the absent of silence doesn't mean speech. Possible approaches depend on the goal

Oh yes the data comes from a mic, how can I implement voice detection? Are there libraries or can you point me to any resources on the subject? Also on denoising, as I said in the post I'm a noob at this and just trying to learn, thanks!!

Not aware of JS counterparts, but I'd check first neural network based ones if relative computational expensiveness isn't the issue. E.g. https://github.com/goepfert/noise_reduction and https://github.com/goepfert/audio_features

I haven't read through all of your code, but these plots of audio samples look weird.  You won't normally have such spikeyness... that would indicate very high frequency noise.  What I suspect is actually happening is that your audio data is not in the format you expect it to be.  Are you for sure getting PCM samples?  Are they in the format you expect?

I am not sure honestly, I am a noob at audio handling, maybe I'm using the wrong format? Maybe I should not normalize inside of convertBufferToAudioBuffer method? I'm sorry if I'm not very helpful but as I said before, I'm just a noob and none of this seem obvious to me

@santiagocalvo Can you start by recording those samples to a file and seeing what it sounds like?  You can use FFmpeg to read in raw samples in a particular format, and output a WAV file.  (Or even, just ffplay to listen to the raw samples.)  That might help inform what you're working with.
